# How do I launch gnome-terminal inside a specified directory?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I created bash script to open terminal in current directory because of [an issue with nautilus-open-terminal](https://askubuntu.com/q/239649/121043).

The problem is, this one doesn't work

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory = "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI"
```

BUt this one works

```
gnome-terminal
cd "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI"
```

Question: what's wrong with first one?

Answer (score 4):

You should not put spaces before and after the `=` sign. The correct command is:

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory="$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI"
```

For completeness, an alternative format is:

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI"
```

(With a blank space *instead of* the `=` sign.)